# triggering a class earlier when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, anchor

I really need your help with this one as I am not good with JS. 
The following function triggers a specific class (.active) when the refElement touches the top of the browser when scrolling down. What I want to do it to trigger it 1em or 2em earlier. 
So how should I edit this?

```
function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.links a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('.links ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

Here you can see it in live action: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
```

to

```
if (refElement.position().top-5 <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top-5 + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
```

adjust the 5 to whatever height you want as your offset.